# Quotient of group schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, functors, group-schemes

Is the following sequence of affine group schemes over $k \in \mathsf{CRing}$ exact, or even for that matter, is there a meaningful notion of quotient of (group) schemes:
$$0 \rightarrow H \rightarrow G \rightarrow G/H \rightarrow 0 $$
Additionally, under which condition is the sequence still exact in $\mathsf{Grp}$ ?
$$0 \rightarrow H(A) \rightarrow G(A) \rightarrow G(A)/H(A) \rightarrow 0 $$
(for any $k$-algebra $A$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general there is not a good of quotients for general bases. Namely, let's fix a ring $R$ and assume that $H\unlhd G$ is a normal containment of flat and finite presentation group schemes over $R$. Then, by standard theory we know that since $G$ and $H$ are representable (by assumption) that $G$ and $H$ are sheaves on the fppf site of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. One can form the fppf sheaf quotient $Q$ (i.e. the $Q$ is the fppf sheafification of $R\mapsto G(R)/H(R)$). One then gets a short exact sequence of group fppf sheaves

$$1\to H\to G\to Q\to 1\qquad (1)$$

on $R$. The issue is that, in general, $Q$ will only be an algebraic space (either in the etale sense or the fppf sense thanks to Artin's theorem).

If $\dim \mathrm{Spec}(k)\leqslant 1$ then, in fact, $Q$ is a scheme (e.g. see [1]) but for higher-dimensional bases this is false (e.g. see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67050/is-the-category-of-affine-fppf-groups-closed-under-normal-quotients)).

Now even in the case when $Q$ is representable one may not have that $(1)$ is exact as a sequence of presheaves. Namely, for any $k$-algebra $A$ one gets an exact sequence of pointed sets

$$1\to H(A)\to G(A)\to Q(A)\to H^1_\text{fppf}(A,H)\to H^1_\text{fppf}(A,G)\to H^1_\text{fppf}(A,Q)$$

(which one can extend further if, for instance, $Q$ is central in $A$). One can define $H^1_\text{fppf}(A,X$) (for a group scheme $X$) to either be

- The set of isomorphism class of $X$-torsors over $A$
- The Cech cohomology of $X$ over $A$

(e.g. see [2, Theorem 6.5.10] for the equivalence). Note that if $X$ is a smooth group scheme over $A$ then one can replace 'fppf torsors' with 'etale torsors' in the case when you assume that $\dim(\mathrm{Spec}(k))\leqslant 1$--for then any $X$-torsor is representable (see loc.cit.) and then one uses the fact that a smooth $X$-group scheme has a section etale locally.

Note that in the torsor language one associates in $(1)$ to any $\alpha\in Q(A)$ the fiber in $G_A$ which, as one can easily check, is a $G_A$-torsor.

[1] S. Anantharaman. *Schemas en groupes, espaces homogenes et espaces algebriques sur une base de dimension 1* Bull. Soc. Math. France, M´emoire 33 (1973), 5–79.

[2] Poonen, B., 2017. *Rational points on varieties* (Vol. 186). American Mathematical Soc.

Comment: Thank you. It is very valuable.

Comment: Are there ways in which we could put restrictions on the group scheme $G$ (and $H$) so that the quotient $Q$ is still a scheme ?

Comment: @DatMinhHa Sure, but not super general ones. I'd cntrl f "quotient" in Brian Conrad's book "Reductive Group Schemes"

Answer (score 5):

The answer for your first question.

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are group schemes over $k$, $H\subseteq G$. Consider $G, H$ as fpqc sheaves on $\textbf{Alg}_k$. Then the quotient $G/H$ exists in the category of fpqc sheaves and your sequence is (by definition) exact as a sequence of pointed objects in this category.

If in addition $H$ and $G$ are affine, of finite type over $k$ and $k$ is a field, then the fpqc sheaf $G/H$ is representable by a $k$-scheme of finite type.

This can be found in Demazure's and Gabriel's book *Groupes algébriques. Tome I: Géométrie algébrique, généralités, groupes commutatifs*. You can also find this fact in Jantzen's book *Representations of Algebraic Groups* and in *SGA III*.

Comment: Is this really true without restrictions on $k$? For example I know his to be true if $\dim(\mathrm{Spec}(k))\leqslant 1$, but I thought this was false in general? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67050/is-the-category-of-affine-fppf-groups-closed-under-normal-quotients

Comment: @AlexYoucis you are right. The aforementioned book of Demazure and Gabriel assumes that $k$ is a field in order to get representability. I am quite sure that other sources above also assume that. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: You may then want to mention as well that in essentially all situations one can replace fpqc by fppf which seems more approachable. You may aslo explain why cohomology answers the OPs second question.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I would happily upvote your potential answer clearing up these issues. I think that in order to answer the second question one needs to use some sort of non-abelian sheaf cohomology on fpqc site (note that we are discussing noncommutative groups). I don't feel competent for that task.

Comment: I will perhaps if I get some time.

Comment: I added a quick answer.

Comment: @Slup could you expand a bit on your answer, particular on 2 points: 1. Could you give a proof sketch ? and 2. Why the fpqc instead of fppf or etale topology ?